# Ng-Click Won't Work After HTML is Passed From Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, angularjs, flask

I am trying to make it so that when I click an `<a>` tag a `<div>` appears on the first click and disappears on the second.

Easy enough right?

Just do this...

`<a href ng-click="clicked=!clicked">Click me</a> 
 <div ng-show="clicked">
SOME CONTENT HERE
 </div>`

and that works perfectly.

But what I'm doing is setting a variable in Python equal to this `<a href='"#"' ng-click='"clicked=!clicked"'>Click me</a>` and then passing that through Flask into the front end (HTML). The passing works perfectly. It shows exactly the same code as I want it to (see below).

`<a href ng-click="clicked=!clicked">Click me</a>`

But for some reason, when I pass it, it loses the `ng-show`/`ng-click` functionality. When I click, nothing appears or disappears.

Why is this?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, you shouldn't pass HTML in a Python variable. Generally you want to include it in your template and use an if statement to determine if it's shown. 

Is the generated code nested in an Angular controller?